# Lotus Notes: Difference between hour

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotus-formula

I have two editable fields (Time1 and Time2), both in calendar/time type, 24hr format. Both are showing the time for example, 20:15, and I also have a computed for display field that will show the difference between two fields.

I've tried difference := (Time1 - Time2), but didn't work.

Any other way to get the difference between the two?

Comment: Just subtracting the items should normally give you the difference in seconds. What exactly do you get? Did you wrap the difference in an error in case one of the fields is not yet filled out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Formula in a computed field:

```
_diff := Time1 - Time2;
@If( @IsError( _diff ); 0; _diff )
```

If the field is of type date time, then you get the difference in hours/minutes
If the field is of type number, then you get the difference in seconds.

Don't forget the @IsError, otherwise your form will not open unless you have valid default values for Time1 and Time2

Comment: Somehow I was not able to reproduce error in the operation `Time1 - Time2`. I tried with both fields blank, one field blank. In both cases the formula did not return error and computed field was blank. Did I miss something here? I used Date/Time field with just `Display Time` past turned on in Field properties.

Comment: Then This has been fixed in a version since I last tested... As I always wrap any calculation / date-time manipulation in @iserror to prohibit "strange results" I just did not realize...

Answer (score 1):

The formula in computed for display would be simply written as:

```
Time1 - Time2
```

Another thing to check is that you would have hit refresh (hit F5 or Ctrl+F5 depending on which version of Lotus Notes you have) to compute the value in computed field once Time1 and Time2 are filled.